# SCALA - Curly brackets in subtype declarations

Tags: scala

In the following code,

```
trait SwingApi {

    type ValueChanged <: Event

    val ValueChanged: {
       def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]
    }

    type ButtonClicked <: Event

    val ButtonClicked: {
        def unapply(x: Event): Option[Button]
    }

    type TextField <: {
        def text: String
        def subscribe(r: Reaction): Unit
        def unsubscribe(r: Reaction): Unit
    }

    type Button <: {
        def subscribe(r: Reaction): Unit
        def unsubscribe(r: Reaction): Unit
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain to me, what we mean by

```
    val ValueChanged: {
       def unapply(x: Event): Option[TextField]
    }
```

and

```
    val ButtonClicked: {
        def unapply(x: Event): Option[Button]
    }
```

What's the name for this pattern so that I can search for more details on Google.

Comment: Those are [structural types](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-duck-typing-in-scala-structural-types/) and in general you should prefer different solutions since those use runtime reflection under the hood.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Sounds cool. That's the solution. Mind if you answer it and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: A good answer should explain in details what is happening, not just a link. But I am too lazy to do that, feel free to answer your own question with all details and I will happily upvote it :)

Comment: That basically is something so called `duck-type inheritance`, which in the code above, it means that whatever type that has function ` unapply()` in it is accepted, which probably is used for pattern matching

Comment: @AminMal It's not duck typing - it's more or less safe statically, unless you use `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf`. The only thing is that it's structural instead of nominal, and uses reflection.

Comment: @OP I changed your question's title, but now I'm not so sure I should have done that, since it doesn't quite match the body of the question. If you want, you can roll it back.

Comment: @user I probably want to roll it back because I want to keep those keywords, like "curly brakets" because I know people like me might search for these keywords :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those things in curly braces are structural types. [Nominal typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) (which Scala usually uses) is when two types are equal if their names match. [Structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) is when two types are considered equal if their contents match.

A structural type like this means that `buttonClicked` is of some type that has an `unapply` method with the given signature. It does not matter what type that is, what its name is, just that it has that method, so that we can call the `unapply` method.

```scala
{
  def unapply(x: Event): Option[Button]
}
```

You can also refine a nominal or compound type. For example, if you want `buttonClicked` to be a `String` and an `Int` with an `unapply` method, it would be written like this:

```
String with Int {
  def unapply(x: Event): Option[Button]
}
```

Structural types are usually not recommended, mainly because the JVM does not support them. Because of this, the compiler generates code that uses reflection to access `unapply` or whatever other methods you have in your structural type. `isInstanceOf`, `asInstanceOf`, and pattern matching also don't work with structural types, since they're erased, so you can find yourself in a situation where your code compiles but there's an error at runtime because a method doesn't exist.

Scala 3 may bring safer [programmatic structural types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/structural-types.html).

Comment: I was going to ask you what you mean by your comment on the question `It's not duck typing`, then I saw your answer and that was complete and great, thank you!